# useSelector value not changed immediately after react redux thunk executed

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I have a useSelector that would return me the value stored in global state, I also have a async action by using react redux thunk which inside it would change the state value, however, when I call my thunk function and after it finishes, the useSelector value seems not update immediately, it would have a little delay...How could I fetch the latest value from state after executing the thunk function?

```
// thunk
function savePageData() {
  return async(dispatch, getState) => {
    await fetch(...).then(res => dispatch(LOAD_DATA, res));
    dispatch(somethingelse);
  }
}

// main
const myPage = () => {
   const user = useSelector(state => return state.user);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const onClick = async() => {
      await dispatch(savePageData());
      if (user.active).   // here the user after above dispatch is still the old state
      { ... }
   }
}
```

it would work this way

```
const onClick = async() => {
    return (_dispatch, getState) => {
      await dispatch(savePageData());
      if (getState().user.active).   // now user is latest, but is this a correct way and why?
      { ... }
    }
}
```

or this way

```
const onClick = async() => {
      await dispatch(savePageData()).then(
        if (user.active).   // now user is latest, but is this a correct way and why?
         { ... }
      );
   }
```